# How do I catch an error at two different points in RxJS/Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Suppose this Angular 2 snippet:

```
export class ApiService {
  // do stuff
  request(...): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.request(...)
      .share()
      .catch((error: any) => {
        let errMsg = 'my error';
        // do more stuff...
        // tried: throw errMsg;
        // tried: return Observable.throw(errMsg);
      });
  }
}
```

Then:

```
api.request(...).catch(() => {
  console.log('caught');
  return Observable.from([]);
}).subscribe({
  console.log('everything fine');
});
```

The `next` callback passed to `subscribe` does get called just fine when the request succeeds, but the callback passed to `catch` doesn't.

I've trying do deal with the error in two different parts of the code that have different responsibilities. I'd like that the error message thrown at the `ApiService.request` would end up in the second callback so I could further refine my response to the user. I've tried both `throw errMsg` and returning `Observable.throw(errMsg)`.

The reason why I'm using `.share()` for the observable is because I don't want the http client to be generating one request per subscriber.

Where am I getting this wrong?

**EDIT:**

My example above didn't really capture the problem I was having. This second snippet allows for the reproduction of it:

```
const a = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
  observer.error('h');
}).share().catch(err=> {
  console.error('first place',err);
  throw 'err'
})
.subscribe(() => null)
.subscribe(console.log, console.error);
```

The first subscribe was failing to catch the error (by not having an error handler defined) and breaking the chain to the second subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you want to catch the error in two places . As per docs you need to use `throw` . I tried and its working fine for me . Here is the code snippet :

```
const a = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
    observer.error('h');
});

a.catch(err=> {
   console.error('first place',err);
   throw 'err'
}).subscribe(console.log,console.error);
```

Output

```
x first place 
x err
```

JSBin : https://jsbin.com/jefalazibo/edit?html,js,console

In the component code you dont need to write another catch . `subscribe` takes three functions as arguments

```
 subscribe(onSuccess, onError, onComplete);
```

Documentation : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/catch.ts 
( check example 3 )

Comment: Does defining onError have the same effect of catching a second time?

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by catching second time . What it does is : when there is an error, instead of executing `onSuccess` function, it executes the `onError` function . That is the right way to do. We use `catch` if we want to catch exceptions and change what is returned in the stream. usually done at service level, not in component.

Comment: We use `catch` in component when we are not using `subscribe` but using `async` directly in HTML . That is different story

Comment: I meant to ask if specifying onError had the same effect of specifying a catch function. I got now that they have different purposes. Doing the way you said doesn't seem to work here... I'm gonna try to find what's different and get back to you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. If its simple you can create a plnkr or stackblitz so that I can help you out.

Comment: Found the problem. I had another subscribe that didn't have an error handler specified. That was breaking the chain: https://jsbin.com/kecicegoxi/edit?html,js,console